# Open Access, Import module and run macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file and I want to open an Access database, import a module named "mod_HelloAccess.bas" and run two macros, one without parameter and another with one parameter.

Everything works fine until it tries to run the macro, where this error occurs **Microsoft Access cannot find the object 'HelloAccess.'**.

What is the problem?
To run the macro with a parameter, the syntax e correct?

```
Sub Excel_RunMacroOnAccess()

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    ' Access object
    Dim appAccess As Object
    
    ' Create new access object
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    
    ' Open the access project
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase (ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value)
    
    ' Show Access
    appAccess.Visible = True
    
    ' Module to be imported
    Dim modFile As String: modFile = "C:\dbTest\mod_HelloAccess.bas"
    
    ' If module exists
    If Len(Dir(modFile)) > 0 Then
        ' Import module
        appAccess.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import modFile
        
        ' Save modules
        appAccess.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCompileAndSaveAllModules
        
        ' Run macro: without parameters
        appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "HelloAccess"
        ' ERROR: Microsoft Access cannot find the object 'HelloAccess.'
        
        ' Run macro: with one parameter
        appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "Hello", "World"
    End If
    
exitRoutine:
    ' Close database
    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
    
    ' Close Access
    appAccess.Quit
    
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume exitRoutine
End Sub
```

File **mod_HelloAccess.bas**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "mod_HelloAccess"
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function HelloAccess()
    msgbox "Hello Access!", vbExclamation
End Sub

Function Hello(Optional word As String = "World")
    msgbox "Hello " & word & "!", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Comment: You are importing a code module. That's not a macro in Access. Call the _function_ you wish to execute by its name.

Comment: @Gustav, I replaced ``appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "HelloAccess"`` with ``appAccess.Run "HelloAccess"`` and it worked. Thanks!